# Why .css() not work on conditional statements bool it true?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function() {

  if ($("p").text().length > 20) {
    console.log("length > 20")
    $(this).text().css("color", "red")
  } else {
    console.log("opps")
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quisquam asperiores eius quasi assumenda error dolorem? Quo sit quaerat ex quia inventore totam, officiis beatae, explicabo quod vitae et exercitationem.</p>
```

in the case. console show $(...).text(...).css is not a function

i don't know where wrong ? even test use .text() also not feelback

why p tag inside text dones't become red color word? ?

Comment: yes because `.text` does not gives you a dom element.

Comment: also if you want to change color of element use element. dont use `text().css()`. text will give string and it wont have css method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.text()` returns a *string*. Strings do not have a `.css` method - only jQuery collections have the `.css` method.

Also, `this` in your code does not refer to the `<p>`. Save the `<p>` jQuery collection in a variable first in order to call `.css` on it (or call `$('p')` again).

```js
const $p = $("p");
if ($p.text().length > 20) {
  console.log("length > 20")
  $p.css("color", "red")
} else {
  console.log("opps")
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quisquam asperiores eius quasi assumenda error dolorem? Quo sit quaerat ex quia inventore totam, officiis beatae, explicabo quod vitae et exercitationem.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `$(this).text().css("color", "red")` to `$("p").css("color", "red")`.

- `.text()` returns string so it won't contain a function `.css()`.
- `$(this)` does not represent `$("p")` here.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("p").text().length > 20) {
    console.log("length > 20");
    console.log($(this));
    $("p").css("color", "red");
  } else {
    console.log("opps")
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quisquam asperiores eius quasi assumenda error dolorem? Quo sit quaerat ex quia inventore totam, officiis beatae, explicabo quod vitae et exercitationem.</p>
```